# Ошибки при обновлении в centos

Tags: centos

делал

```
# yum clean all
```

и собственно апдейт

```
# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
epel/metalink                                                |  24 kB     00:00
 * atomic: www7.atomicorp.com
 * base: ftp.colocall.net
 * epel: ftp.colocall.net
 * extras: ftp.colocall.net
 * rpmforge: ftp.colocall.net
 * updates: ftp.colocall.net
CentALT                                                      |  951 B     00:00
CentALT/primary                                              |  81 kB     00:00
CentALT                                                                 263/263
atomic                                                       | 1.9 kB     00:00
atomic/primary_db                                            | 490 kB     00:01
base                                                         | 3.7 kB     00:00
base/primary_db                                              | 3.4 MB     00:00
epel                                                         | 4.2 kB     00:00
epel/primary_db                                              | 4.7 MB     00:00
extras                                                       | 3.5 kB     00:00
extras/primary_db                                            |  19 kB     00:00
rpmforge                                                     | 1.9 kB     00:00
rpmforge/primary_db                                          | 2.7 MB     00:00
updates                                                      | 3.4 kB     00:00
updates/primary_db                                           | 4.2 MB     00:00
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
There are unfinished transactions remaining.
You might consider running yum-complete-transaction first to finish them.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package abrt.i686 0:2.0.8-15.el6.centos will be updated
...
---> Package protobuf-lite.i686 0:2.3.0-7.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-pecl-imagick-2.2.2-4.el6.i686 (@epel)
       Requires: php(api) = 20090626
       Removing: php-common-5.3.23-16.el6.art.i686 (@atomic)
           php(api) = 20090626
           php(api) = 20090626-x86-32
       Updated By: php-common-5.4.20-26.el6.art.i686 (atomic)
           php(api) = 20100412-x86-32
       Available: atomic-php55-php-common-5.5.4-3.el6.i686 (atomic)
           php(api) = 20121113-32
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.i686 (base)
           php(api) = 20090626
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-23.el6_4.i686 (updates)
           php(api) = 20090626
       Available: php-common-5.3.27-1.el6.i686 (CentALT)
           php(api) = 20090626-x86-32
           php(api) = 20090626
       Available: php-common-5.4.17-23.el6.art.i686 (atomic)
           php(api) = 20100412-x86-32
       Available: php-common-5.4.18-24.el6.art.i686 (atomic)
           php(api) = 20100412-x86-32
       Available: php-common-5.4.19-25.el6.art.i686 (atomic)
           php(api) = 20100412-x86-32
Error: Package: php-pecl-imagick-2.2.2-4.el6.i686 (@epel)
       Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20090626
       Removing: php-common-5.3.23-16.el6.art.i686 (@atomic)
           php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           php(zend-abi) = 20090626-x86-32
       Updated By: php-common-5.4.20-26.el6.art.i686 (atomic)
           php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-32
       Available: atomic-php55-php-common-5.5.4-3.el6.i686 (atomic)
           php(zend-abi) = 20121212-32
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.i686 (base)
           php(zend-abi) = 20090626
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-23.el6_4.i686 (updates)
           php(zend-abi) = 20090626
       Available: php-common-5.3.27-1.el6.i686 (CentALT)
           php(zend-abi) = 20090626-x86-32
           php(zend-abi) = 20090626
       Available: php-common-5.4.17-23.el6.art.i686 (atomic)
           php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-32
       Available: php-common-5.4.18-24.el6.art.i686 (atomic)
           php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-32
       Available: php-common-5.4.19-25.el6.art.i686 (atomic)
           php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-32
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 6 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
ORBit2-2.14.17-3.2.el6_3.i686 is a duplicate with ORBit2-2.14.17-3.1.el6.i686
cpio-2.10-11.el6_3.i686 is a duplicate with cpio-2.10-10.el6.i686
1:dbus-libs-1.2.24-7.el6_3.i686 is a duplicate with 1:dbus-libs-1.2.24-5.el6_1.i686
htop-1.0.2-1.el6.rf.i686 is a duplicate with htop-1.0.1-2.el6.rf.i686
pango-1.28.1-7.el6_3.i686 is a duplicate with pango-1.28.1-3.el6_0.5.1.centos.i686
1:telnet-0.17-47.el6_3.1.i686 is a duplicate with 1:telnet-0.17-47.el6.i686
```

Comment: обновите отдельно php-pecl-imagick-2.2.2-4 или его надо пересобрать или ещё что-то скорее всего у васчасть пакетов установлена не из репов

Comment: не получается.    # yum update php-pecl-imagick    Loaded plugins: fastestmirror    Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile     * atomic: www7.atomicorp.com     * base: ftp.colocall.net     * epel: ftp.colocall.net     * extras: ftp.colocall.net     * rpmforge: ftp.colocall.net     * updates: ftp.colocall.net    Setting up Update Process    No Packages marked for Update

Answer (score 1):

в выводе есть две подсказки:

1. > There are unfinished transactions remaining. You might consider running yum-complete-transaction first to finish them.

   т.е., для завершения незавершённых транзакций надо выполнить:

   ```
   # yum-complete-transaction
   ```
2. > You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem

   можно попробовать пропустить «сломаные» пакеты:

   ```
   # yum update --skip-broken
   ```